# how to get userid in redux action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to print out user related items only.
So i am try to get items by requesting data to user id `/api/items/:userid`
I am using redux store

my server side code is like this

```
router.get("/:userid",(req, res) => {
  // Item.find({ "owner.ownerName": `${req.params.userid}`})
  Item.find({ "owner.id": `${req.params.userid}`})
    .sort({
      date: -1,
    })
    .then((items) => res.json(items));
   console.log(req.user)
});
```

The problem is my front end request.
I don't know how to get user id inside ITEMACTION.

```
import {
  GET_ITEMS,
  ADD_ITEM,
  DELETE_ITEM,
  ITEMS_LOADING,
  UPDATE_ITEM,
  SUBSTRACT_ITEM,
} from "../actions/types";
import { tokenConfig } from "../actions/authActions";
import { returnErrors } from "../actions/errorActions";
import Axios from "axios";

export const getItems = () => (dispatch) => {
  // will hit reducer
  dispatch(setItemsLoading());
  Axios.get("/api/items/")
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ITEMS,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
    });
};
```

I actually tried to get user id from the redux store.

```
import store from '../store';
```

and inside getItems

```
store.getState().auth.user._id
```

the problem is that when i console.log in getItems the user id is always return null except first time after login. But when i look in redux dev tool. The user id is available

[image: Redux store state image]

how can i get the userid

Answer (score 2):

Hey you can get the getState as a second argument in the inner function along with the dispatch, using that you can access the updated state in an action.
Fixed Code:

```
export const getItems = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // will hit reducer
  const userId = getState().auth.user._id;
  console.log(userId) // should output the updated data
  dispatch(setItemsLoading());
  Axios.get("/api/items/")
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ITEMS,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
    });
};
```

store.getState doesn't return updated state, in order to get the updated state using store.getState() you need to subscribe to the state change.

```
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() => {
    // logs the state data everytime an action is dispatched.
    console.log("from listener: ", store.getState());
})
```

[Details here](https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener)